# MapKit - How to change user location icon to default

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to change my pins color, but when I'm adding the code to switch annotation it also changes my location icon (from blue dot to a pin). Any tips how to restore default user location icon?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
    switch annotation.title!! {
        case "Ślęża":
            annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: (69.0/255), green: (95.0/255), blue: (170.0/255), alpha: 1.0)
        case "Śnieżnik":
            annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: (52.0/255), green: (114.0/255), blue: (1.0/255), alpha: 1.0)
        case "test":
            annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: (246.0/255), green: (233.0/255), blue: (212.0/255), alpha: 1.0)
        case "Brooklyn Bridge":
            annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: (146.0/255), green: (187.0/255), blue: (217.0/255), alpha: 1.0)
        default:
            annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check to exclude it

```
guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
```